# How to animate a texture change in Eevee (ideally)?

Tags: animation, texturing

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0glf-acMvcw) to use multiple textures with a slider to show one at a time. In this case it is being used for a cartoon face. Except the Auto Keying is failing to create a keyframe when the slider is used and a texture is changed. How to animate it then?
Ideally in Eevee, but Cycles would be ok.

Thanks guys

Comment: you can use drivers for any slider you have just make an empty and assign a driver for the slider to the empty position.
here is a quick tut: https://youtu.be/5SdKAUsjcsg

Comment: Got it working! Thank you so much Mobin! :)